# Is it possible to append/prepend a text string to JSESSIONID?

Tags: java, jsessionid

Looking for **application server neutral** way of doing this. I would still appreciate all the available options.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the purpose of doing that?

Comment: Its a sticky session cluster. This is needed just to identify the response and server its coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of JSESSIONID depends on application server implementation of the [servlet specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html).

For tomcat, you can configure JSESSIONID with the jvmroute parameter in the Engine configuration : [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/engine.html).

Example: server.xml
[...]

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
```

[...]

HTTP Header received for a new session :
[...]

```
Cookie:JSESSIONID=D258081D2030693CB1BD52992FFE6CFD.jvm1
```

[...]